# Parity (Ethereum) Balances Incorrect

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

**The Question:**
Currently my balances in Parity are wrong. Is there a way to delete my accounts and their history in parity, such that I can re-import the geth keystore files into Parity, and have their balances retrieved from the network?

**Background:**
I sent several transactions out when my Parity node was out of sync, so the request was submitted to the network, and recognized, but the balances in my Parity instance remained the same, and every time I launch it, the transaction still have not been processed/acknowledged by the browser, although the account balances have changed. The node is now synced, yet the balances in Parity do not match the actual account balances; some are higher, some are lower.

For awhile this was okay, because I was just selling the tokens, so I could just check my balance on etherscan.io and then send outward. However, I made the BONEHEAD mistake of transferring some ETH to a Parity account of mine. Since the original balance was 0.1, and now it's more like 2.5, I no longer can access the other 2.4 ETH, because there is insufficient funds in the account. Yeah, whoops!

I have kept all of the original geth keystore files for each of these accounts, which are now in Parity. I have tried to delete them from Parity, and then reimport them, yet the account history (txns attempted in Parity), as well as their balance remain what they were previously. How can I clear the Parity browser's *incorrect assumptions* about my account balances, and have it treat them like newly imported accounts again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That seems more like a bug, if anything. The key files in the `keystores` directory in Parity's data directory only contain data required to access an account, not its history. The transaction list in Parity is drawn from Etherscan; if there's a problem with the API, your transaction list may not be correct. The balance for each account is derived from syncing the blockchain, however.

If there's a bug that clearing history will solve, you can delete the `chains` and `cache` directories from your Parity data directory (location is specific to your operating system and Parity version). Parity will have resync the entire blockchain for your balances to be recalculated in full.

Comment: Thank you. I emptied the cache and chain data folders. The balances are all zero now. Still syncing, but I expect the correct balance will come in (eventually, probably another 24hrs, sigh).